# Adjust the height of table column based on the content inside it

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

How to adjust the height of the `td` based on `iframe` height.
I tried `height:auto`, but it doesn't work. Each `iframe` has different content and hence the height also differs

I am using content carousel to switch between one iframe to other.

Initially what happens is that the content carousel animates automatically switching between each iframes. And then lands at the first iframe. Then the user can use the carousel navigation to switch between iframes.

```
<td class="tabContainer">
<div id="multipleIframe">
<iframe></iframe>
<iframe></iframe>
<iframe></iframe>
<iframe></iframe>
</div>
</td>
```

Below is the code I am using to change the height of each iframe and the `td` height.

```
setTimeout(function() {
$("#multipleIframe iframe").each(function() {
var heightIframe;
heightIframe = $(this).contents().height();
$(this).css({
    "height": heightIframe
});
var tabHeight;
tabHeight = heightIframe + 50;
$(".tabContainer").css({"height":tabHeight+"px"})
});
}, 3000)
```

Can we solve this?

Comment: you are trying to add the heights of all the iframes and then apply that to the td ?

Comment: Yes, which is not working right.

Answer (score 0):

The `tabHeight` value is set to `heightIframe` in each iteration. Place it outside the loop.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  var tabHeight=0; // set it to zero and outside the loop
  $("#multipleIframe iframe").each(function() {
    var heightIframe = $(this).contents().height();
    $(this).css({
      "height": heightIframe + "px" <--- add "px" here too
    });
    tabHeight += heightIframe + 50; // add each iframe's height to tabHeight
  });
  $(".tabContainer").css({"height":tabHeight+"px"}); // apply the tab height
}, 3000);
```

Comment: This is adding up all the height and setting the height. There is too much unwanted space.

Comment: probably because you're adding an extra `50` inside the loop.

Comment: The total height of the div is 1890px. Adding 50 , should not increase so much right. Each iframe height is not more that 700.

Comment: This is how it looks to me. http://jsbin.com/lomega/1/edit?html,js,output Please update your question with probably how big the iframes will be or maybe create a demo that replicates your issue.

Comment: Question updated with description. All iframes are not displayed at once. I use navigation to switch between iframes